# FlutterFire CLI for SHA1

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to add a SHA1 certificate to a new Firebase Project

In the [FlutterFire Overview](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation) there is a statement that the manual configuration should get avoided. Instead we should use the `flutterfire configure` command line with the CLI.

There is no clarification on how to add the SHA1 certificate with the CLI.

Is this even possible? If not should I then do the whole configuration manually?

Answer (score 3):

On the [Social Authentication page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/) of the FlutterFire docs, it says the following:

> Dart-only Firebase initialization isn't yet supported by `google_sign_in` plugin, if you're using Google as an auth provider you'll still have to do the manual installation steps to integrate the Firebase configuration files.

So unfortunately it's not built into the CLI yet. Hope that helps.